# Android Studio - Cannot open Local Terminal: Failed to start [powershell.exe]

Tags: powershell, android-studio, terminal, windows-11, chocolatey

I've encountered an issue with Android Studio where I'm unable to open the local terminal within the IDE. The error message I receive is:

```
Cannot open Local Terminal
Failed to start [powershell.exe] in C:\Users\hab\AndroidStudioProjects\SOS_Project
See IDE log for the details.
```

Steps I've taken to resolve the issue:

- Reinstalled Android Studio.
- Reset Android Studio settings.

Additional Information:

- Android Studio Version: Android Studio Giraffe | 2022.3.1 Patch 2
- OS: Windows 11

Any insights would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

file -> settings -> Terminal -> Application Setting -> shell path: c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe